# Is it possible to set the alignment of kendo datepicker's dropdown calendar in kendo grid with respect to the textbox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

When the datatype is Date, the kendo grid uses a kendo datepicker with dropdown calendar for the column.

The datepicker's dropdown calendar usually aligns itself flush with the *left* edge of the input box. If there isn't room for that, it is moved to the left, but not quite enough. This presents a problem when the rightmost column in the grid is a Date, and the grid is occupying 100% of the width available on the screen: the Saturday column in the dropdown calendar gets "cut off".  See pic attached.

Is it possible to tell the calendar dropdown (for a particular column) to align itself flush with the *right* edge of the text input?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that bug. Your datepicker animation container is hidden under right scrollbar. If you set body overflow to hidden, you will not have a scrollbars and calendar will fit and touch right border of screen, like in this example: http://dojo.telerik.com/UCOhA

However if you can't turn off the body scrollbars you need to set calendar position manually dirty way like this:

```
$("#piker").kendoDatePicker({
    open: function(e) {
      //setTimeout to let kendo make k-animation-container element at first open
      setTimeout(function(){
        var animationContainer = $("#" + e.sender.element.attr("id") + "_dateview").parent();
        var left = e.sender.element.offset().left + e.sender.element.closest('.k-datepicker').width() - animationContainer.width();
        animationContainer.css('left', left);
      });
    },
  //turnoff the animation to avoid strange visual effects
  animation: {
   open: {
     duration: 0
   }
  }
});
```

Running example: http://dojo.telerik.com/Imiqa/2